# JavaScript and php, malfunction with the array image

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

I have created a chess board in php, and put the chess piece according to their order. Everything is working, but I cannot change the color of the king piece when I point the mouse on it and I have to use javascript to prompt a message to user on the details of the chess when the user clicks any of the piece of the chess, here I have to use javaScript to do it. Is there any suggestion, how should I approach. Please refer to my coding below, what should I change or add to get it working.

```
<html> 
<head> 
<style> 
            th{ 
                width:80px; 
                height:80px; 
            } 
            table{ 
                border: 5px solid #FFBB78; 
                border-collapse:collapse; 
            } 
            td{ 
                width:80px; 
                height:80px; 
            } 
            tr{ 
                width:80px; 
                height:80px;  
            } 
            h1{ 
                color:#6633FF; 
            } 
</style> 

<script type="text/javascript"> 
function changeColor(){
    document.getElementById("king").style.backgroundColor="yellow";//this image has to change color.
 }
</script> 
</head> 
<body> 
<?php 

    $pictures = array( 
        //row 1
        "1,1" => '<img src="chess/br.gif" />',  
        "1,3" => '<img src="chess/bb.gif"/>', 
        "1,4" => '<img src="chess/bq.gif"/>',
        "1,5" => '<img src="chess/bk.gif"/>',
        "1,8" => '<img src="chess/br.gif"/>',
        //row 2
        "2,1" => '<img src="chess/bp.gif"/>', 
        "2,2" => '<img src="chess/bp.gif"/>', 
        "2,3" => '<img src="chess/bp.gif"/>', 
        "2,4" => '<img src="chess/bp.gif"/>', 
        "2,5" => '<img src="chess/bb.gif"/>', 
        "2,6" => '<img src="chess/bp.gif"/>', 
        "2,7" => '<img src="chess/bp.gif"/>', 
        "2,8" => '<img src="chess/bp.gif"/>',

        //row 3
        "3,3" => '<img src="chess/bn.gif"/>',
        "3,6" => '<img src="chess/bn.gif"/>',

        //row 4
        "4,5" => '<img src="chess/bp.gif"/>',

        //row 5
        "5,3" => '<img src="chess/wb.gif"/>',
        "5,5" => '<img src="chess/wp.gif"/>',

        //row 6 
        "6,4" => '<img src="chess/wp.gif"/>',
        "6,6" => '<img src="chess/wn.gif"/>',

        //row 7
        "7,1" => '<img src="chess/wp.gif"/>',
        "7,2" => '<img src="chess/wp.gif"/>',
        "7,3" => '<img src="chess/wp.gif"/>',
        "7,6" => '<img src="chess/wp.gif"/>',
        "7,7" => '<img src="chess/wp.gif"/>',
        "7,8" => '<img src="chess/wp.gif"/>',

        //row 8
        "8,1" => '<img src="chess/wr.gif"/>',//this are the chess piece that has to prompt out chess piece details
        "8,2" => '<img src="chess/wn.gif"/>',
        "8,3" => '<img src="chess/wb.gif"/>',
        "8,4" => '<img src="chess/wq.gif"/>',
        "8,6" => '<img src="chess/wr.gif"/>',
        "8,7" => '<img src="chess/wk.gif"/";);//this image has to change color.//array ends here

    echo"<h1 align='center'>SAJID Chess Board</h1>"; 
    echo"<table border='1' align='center'>"; 

     for($i = 1; $i <= 8; $i++){      
          echo "<tr>"; 
          for($j = 1; $j <=8; $j++){ 
              if( ($i+$j)%2==0 ) { 
                echo"<td bgcolor='#99FF99'>"; 
              } 
              else { 
                echo"<td bgcolor='#9999CC'>"; 
                   } 


                if(isset($pictures["{$i},{$j}"]))//compares the pictures i and p 
                    echo $pictures["{$i},{$j}"]; 

                echo "</td>"; 
                } 
                echo "</tr>"; 
            } 


            echo "</table>"; 

        ?> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: onmouseover isn't a tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onmouseover` isn't a tag, it's an attribute for a tag.  `onmouseover` needs to be a part of the img tag.  Changing that one line will get you on track, like this:

```
"8,7" => '<img src="chess/wk.gif" onmouseover="changeColor()" id="king" />',);//array ends here
```

Comment: ooooo, yeaahhhh! Thansks Surreal.. only for 1 line I was sitting more than an hour.. thank you soo much

Comment: perhaps you need also to include jquery and move onmouseover into jquery events, based on this question; what about other pieces or even empty squares? just give a class to all pieces/squares and change from there.

Comment: Glad I could help.  @vlzvl makes an **excellent** point - jQuery will let you write "unobtrusive" JavaScript, so your PHP can output the HTML and your JavaScript can stay separate in it's own file.  jQuery will also let you easily target different board squares (ie, by color) or squares containing certain pieces, no matter where that piece gets moved.  It adds a lot of power to your code - it's how I wish JavaScript was written to begin with.

Comment: Mr Surreal, can you just do 1 more favour, how do I prompt message, I am using a function and variable, for example when I click on the KNIGHT piece, it will prompt a message saying that it is a KNIGHT

Comment: You can accomplish this with the `alert()` function.  Here's a [brief tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptalert.php) on the subject.